# Systemd - unable to setup speed/duplex of ethernet interface

Tags: systemd, udev

I am trying to setup the ethernet interface of an embedded device to run with e.g. 10 MBit/s / half-duplex.

Since the system uses systemd (systemd-networkd) for configuring network devices, the usual way might be to define a proper .link file, which I tried:

```
/lib/systemd/network/20-eth0.link:
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
MTUBytes=1450
BitsPerSecond=10M
Duplex=half
```

Calling `udevadm info /sys/class/net/eth0` tells me that the link file was loaded and even the MTU value was properly adopted.
But neither speed nor duplex mode was changed - `ethtool eth0` outputs:

```
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Link detected: yes
```

I also tried so set the values within an udev rule right away:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/10-persistent-network.rules:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth*", ATTR{speed}="10", ATTR{duplex}="half", ATTR{mtu}="1400"
```

which brings me to the same result: MTU value is adopted but neither speed nor duplex mode

On the other hand it is no problem to manually set these attributes using `ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex half`

My suggestion is that somehow the driver loads the default values afterwards since one of the last messages of `dmesg` after startup says:

`xilinx_axienet xilinx_axienet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx`

But I am not sure if this really overwrites my settings or that the settings were not taken at all (because they are set somewhere else with higher precedence e.g.)

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - `systemctl status systemd-udevd` gave me the first needed hint.

First, `Name` is no valid `Match` option value for **.link** but it is for **.network** - it was still loaded for the ethernet device though.

The more interesting information was that `udevd` complained about invalid arguments for setting speed/duplex which guided me to [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413187/is-systemd-links-handling-of-auto-negotiation-broken) where a bug in `systemd` prevents the configuration of speed/duplex mode via .link file.This bug was fixed with version `v237`

The funny thing now is that it even did not work when running `v237` because `v237` has another bug preventing this approach. So I recommend to update to at least `v239` to have both bugs fixed.

And if someone else also needs to patch an older version of `systemd` here are the 2 related bugs:

- [bug within systemd v236 and older](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7808)
- [bug within at least v237](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/8889)